# Can a Chrome extension toggle Switches normally set as command line flags?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering if I would be able to write a chrome extension that would be able to toggle Switches in the browser, similar to how using the command line flag: "--disable-web-security" works.

In an ideal world, I would only set this flag for a single tab, but the ability to toggle the security flag on and off within the browser would be a good start.

Any ideas on if/how this can be accomplished?

Comment: There's no normal way to do it as it would present an enormous security risk. But there's always a possibility to try to hack the process using platform exploits and a native extension. Of course such thing will never be accepted on webstore.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was starting to think this might be the case. No intentions on bringing it to the webstore, just looking for an alternative to running command line flags and putting any simultaneous browsing at a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API for this.